# Android get all media files on the whole filesystem (SD card + internal stroage)

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I want to get the list of all the media files in the whole filesystem i.e. from the external as well as internal storage. How can we do it? Can content providers be used to scan internal storage media? Or scannning through the whole file system for the desired extension like ".mp3" is good enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only interested in audio media then you need the following content providers:

`MediaStore.Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`
`MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`

Android is scanning automatically the files and keeping content providers for audio, pictures and video (and the generic files) up to date.